# Some application GUIs do not render correctly since updating to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gui, lts, desktop-apps

I use Ubuntu on VirtualBox but I haven't used it for some time. I launched it today and upgraded the release to 22.04, however since the update I have noticed some of my apps GUI do not render correctly.

I had MYSQL Workbench installed and when I tried to launch it, the app would appear black and none of the text was visible:

[image: MYSQL Workbench GUI Issue]

I have the same problem with Postman, as you can see in the below screenshot. When I click on the *Choose* button to set the location of the working directory, the pop-up window does not render correctly and appears to be transparent:

The title bar at the top of the app is also not displaying fully.

[image: screenshot of application]

Comment: Hi @Nmath, thanks for your comments. I am not 100% sure what the last version was. Was either 18.04 or 20.04. If I had to guess, it would be 20.04. I believe it was updated using 'Software Updater' as I had the pop-up saying new version available. I didn't open the applications before I updated to 22.04. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no luck. I use Postman's and MYSQL's official sites to install either via terminal or if available to download and unzip. For Postman, I have also tried installing via the 'Ubuntu Software' but that version has not been updated in over 1 year.

Comment: Just to add, I have setup another VM using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and there are no issues at all with the applications. There must be something causing a conflict when upgrading to 22.04.

Comment: Why don't you install  a new 22.04 VM?

Comment: @Pilot6 I have tried doing a clean install with a new 22.04 VM and still the same issues

Answer (score 0):

I'm having exactly the same issue. Java applications are only displayed correctly if I use an external screen. They appear black as in your screenshots only if I use my laptop's screen. Also running Ubuntu 22.04 in VirtualBox and, after trying multiple combinations in Display settings, I managed to make it work by selecting VMSVGA Graphic Controller and disabling 3D acceleration. Also I increased Video memory to 128MB.

[image]